# Put UIElement to ListBox with custom ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, listbox, itemtemplate, uielement

I have an array of `System.Windows.Controls.Image` and I assign it to `ListBox.ItemsSource`.

What's more, I want to have a `Border` around each `Image`.

The xaml below demonstrates my idea.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="2" Style="{StaticResource borderStyle}"
                    Child="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

As you know, Child is not a dependency property; the code won't work.

So how should I put the Image (or the ListBox item) in the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ContentControl` should do the trick:

```
<Border BorderThickness="2" Style="{StaticResource borderStyle}">
  <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
</Border>
```

Comment: @LoveRight wow - that was a good guess. I was only ~ 50% sure it would work :-)